# What is the name of this reference class design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, language-agnostic

Is there a name for the design pattern where a single class is written to contain references to commonly used objects, which are usually singletons? And is it wise to use such a class or is there a better way to do this?

Here's an example:

```
public class References {
  AccountManager accountManager = new AccountManager();
  UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
  TransactionHandler handler = new TransactionHandler();
  Calculator calc = new Calculator();
  /// etc.
}
```

Comment: How is the `References` class used?

Comment: It's called a "God object", and it's not a good idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object

Comment: @jaco0646 Any class that needs to use the AccountManager or other singletons would get it from the References class.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Is it still considered a God object if it only has references but no methods?